# meaning of "to move up the stack"

Tags: meaning, expressions

What's the exact meaning of this expression?

Here's a sample sentence I faced:

> In the end, both web browsers and web servers turned out to be commodities, and value moved "up the stack" to services delivered over the web platform.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technical question more than an English question. "The stack" refers to different layers of a model of network communication, similar to [this one for more general network communication](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/osi-model-diagram.html). "The stack" has physical connectivity at the bottom, network protocols like HTTP a little higher, specific browsers and servers in the middle and the applications being distributed at the top.

The place where value is to be found has moved 'up the stack" from browsers to applications.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to be sure what the author's intention is, but [**the stack**](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/08/what-is-a-full-stack-developer/)  refers to the layers of hardware and software built upon one another for modern IT purposes.

Without going into details, *the stack* goes something like

1. bare bits - how processors interpret machine language
2. how operating systems manage files, RAM, device drivers
3. low level languages like C
4. high level languages like Python
5. large programs, in your case maybe a webserver like Apache
6. toolkits written to make working with those programs easier
7. apps or what-have-you written in those toolkits

The list can be filled out and extended, but you get the idea from the given skeletal structure.  Given this, the author may have meant

> moved "up the stack" to services delivered over the web platform

to mean **solving a problem with something like [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), somewhere around #6 above, that was formerly solved with local executable programs**, like Microsoft Excel or even straight C/Python, which are up around #3-5 in the stack.